# Creating mean and sum dataframe using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have this dataframe whereby I wish to calculate the **mean and sum** from the column 'Score'. I do not want to use the .groupby().agg() method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Country': ['Germany', 'Germany', 'Canada', 'Canada'], 
'Score': [8, 4, 35, 50], 
 'Continent': ['Europe', 'Europe', 'North America', 'North America']},
columns=['Country','Score','Continent'])
print (df)
```

Dataframe becomes:

```
   Country          Score      Continent
0  Germany              8         Europe
1  Germany              4         Europe
2   Canada             35  North America
3   Canada             50  North America
```

The easiest method I have found is:

```
new_df = df.groupby('Continent')['Score'].agg({'sum': np.sum, 'avg': np.average})

Continent               
Europe          12   6.0
North America   85  42.5
```

I now have 2 series average and total. How do I make that into a new dataframe using the index from .groupby('Continent')?

I'm trying to use the **group, frame method** here:

```
for group, frame in df.groupby('Continent'):
        avg = np.average(frame['Score'])
        total = np.sum(frame['Score']) 
        df['avg'] = avg
        df['sum'] = total
```

Comment: new_df is a dataframe with two columns and the index is 'continent'.  .agg with dictionary rename is depreciated and as of pandas version 0.20.0

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what the output should be?

Comment: The output should be the same as the easiest method using .groupby().agg(). But I want to do this using a loop then construct the dataframe using the two series df['avg] and df['sum']

Comment: It's still not clear what you want.  Maybe this?  `df.groupby('Continent')['Score'].transform(np.mean)`